# Select List issue

Tags: selectlist

I am facing issues with select list . I have a table of records and i am trying to fetch the selected picklist value in the controller .
 However seems like it is always fetching the last value .Below is the code .

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedString}" title="Abc" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!abs.optionsList}" id="serviceType" />
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action=" {!createValues} "reRender="section1">
        <apex:param name="testParam" value=" {!abs.abdata.Id}" assignTo="{!abId}"/>
    </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:selectList>
```

---

```
public void createValues(){
    system.debug('Value of nbId *********** ' + nbId);
    system.debug('Value of selectedString *********** ' + selectedString);
    nbIdList.add(nbId);
    selectedStringList.add(selectedString);
    system.debug('Value of selectedStringList *********** ' + selectedStringList);
}
```

For instance if i have two rows of data in the table and initially the value of picklist for both rows is 7 and then
if the corresponding selected value of picklist for row  1 and row 2 is changed to 33 and 34
respectively .Then selectedStringList shows values as 33 and 7 . Not sure why ,
Can some one please look into it

Comment: We would need to see more code than what you've shared here to confirm what the problem is, but it sounds like you've bound more than one input to a single variable, which is bound to cause problems. If you would like more definitive help, please [edit] your question to include all relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you bind all selectList with single variable `selectedString`. So when you select the value it always keeps the last selected value and overrides the previous one.

As per your code `abs.abdata.Id` it looks like you are using wrapper list. So declare a variable in that list and then bind that variable in select list.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!abs.selectedString}" title="Abc" size="1">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!abs.optionsList}" id="serviceType" />
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action=" {!createValues}" reRender="section1">
    <apex:param name="testParam" value=" {!abs.abdata.Id}" assignTo="{!abId}"/>
</apex:actionSupport>
```